# Spring-Cloud-Config Custom Environment Repository

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am trying to build a Spring Cloud Configuration server that retrieves properties from a proprietary property server (not Git) using a RefreshScope annotation on the clients to re-inject changed properties

Since there are lots of properties and processing, I want to be able to do a conditional request, so that if no properties are changed since the supplied date, nothing will be injected.

I implemented the EnvironmentRepository interface and overrode the findOne() method to only retrieve the properties if they have changed, and otherwise return an empty map.

I also tried returning null from findOne() but that causes a NullPointerException to be thrown in the config server.

If I return the environment object, the properties are re-injected correctly, but I am trying to avoid that in the case where there are no changes

Does Spring provide some hook method where the config server can notify the config client to leave its properties as they are, and not to re-inject its properties?

​

Comment: One possible solution is to throw an exception rather than return a null ConfigurableEnvironment. But granted that is not a very palatable hack!